# Initialize the defaultValue of EditTextPreference via java code

Tags: java, android, xml, initialization, android-preferences

I have an EditTextPreference and I want to initialize with a default value which will be the path of a specific directory. But I don't understand how to do this. I have made many search but nothing works.

My second question is how to initialize an string-array which will permit to initialize a ListPreference with the available sizes of the camera.

Comment: I use getEditText() into my PreferenceActivity and when I execute into the debug I see my new value set but into my prefs layout when I touch the EditTextPreference I have nothing

Answer (score 0):

Use getEditText() on the EditTextPreference, then use setText() on the EditText.